# monacaでCordova4.1からCordova5.2にバージョンアップしたら音声ファイルの再生ができなくなった

Tags: monaca, cordova

monacaでCordova4.1からCordova5.2にバージョンアップしたところmediaプラグインでの効果音再生が動かなくなりました。
monacaデバッガーでは動きますが、ビルドしてiOS端末で動かすと音がなりません。
バージョンアップ前は鳴りました。

音を鳴らす部分は下記URLの
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/tips/media/
「PhoneGap の Media API を使用した、音の再生」というところのサンプルソースと同じことをやっています。
Cordovaプラグインの管理画面でMediaプラグインはONになっています。
バージョンアップに伴いMediaプラグインを利用する部分は何かソースの書き換えが必要でしょうか。
ご存じのかたいたら教えてください。

Comment: Cordovaプラグインを一旦削除して再追加してみるか、新規にプロジェクトを開始してアプリを再構成してみてください。それでうまくいくようならmonacaの問題でしょう。Cordovaバージョンアップの際に何か不具合が紛れ込んだのだと思います。

Comment: 何も変えずに再度ビルドしたら直りました。Monacaの不具合対応で直ったようです。
以下、該当の情報を転記↓
-------------------
障害・不具合情報
2015/11/24 00:00 JST
BasicプランとPersonalプランをご利用の方を対象に、Cordova5系プロジェクトにて作成したビルドアプリとカスタムデバッガーに、プラグインが正常にインストールされない不具合が発生しておりました。
2015/11/30 12:30 JST
不具合の修正を完了いたしました。

Comment: 解決の報告でしたら、コメントではなくぜひ回答として投稿してください。解決したことが明白になります。

Answer (score 1):

何も変えずに再度ビルドしたら直りました。
Monacaの不具合対応で直ったようです。 
以下、[障害情報ページ](https://ja.monaca.io/headline/fault.html)より該当の情報を引用します。

> 2015/11/24 00:00 JST 
>   BasicプランとPersonalプランをご利用の方を対象に、Cordova5系プロジェクトにて作成したビルドアプリとカスタムデバッガーに、プラグインが正常にイ‌​ンストールされない不具合が発生しておりました。
>
> 2015/11/30 12:30 JST 
>   不具合の修正を完了いたしました。